# Question about Eulers formula $v - e + f = 2$

Tags: graph-theory

Generally the theorem by Euler is stated:

If $G$ is connected and planar then $v - e + f = 2$ (where $v$ is the number of vertices, $e$ is the number of edges and $f$ is the number of faces of the graph $G$).

My question is:

Is this theorem an equivalence? I.e. is it true that if the equation $v - e + f = 2$ holds for a graph $G$ then $G$ is connected and planar.

Really thankful for any help with this. I couldn't find a counter-example myself, (i.e. a graph for which $v - e + f = 2$ holds but is either not connected or not planar) but I guess the theorem would be stated as an equivalence if it were an equivalence...

Comment: The Euler Characteristic is connected to the Genus of the surface on which the graph is drawn.

Comment: Okey, interesting. Can you expand on that? I'm not familiar with the term Genus.

Comment: The number $f$ of faces doesn't make sense if the graph isn't drawn on a surface without crossings.

Comment: Here are some links which may help - the classification of surfaces is relevant also to your question, as it tells you which surfaces have which genus - but the surfaces have to be non-pathalogical: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics); http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic

Comment: Thanks for all the input! But how about if you would think about the faces as the faces that arise if there would be a vertice in every crossing. Isn't that a possible way to think about/define the faces in a non-planar graph?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the graph is planar makes it clear what the faces are. If you take an abstract graph, you must specify where you will put the faces... and since you can put them everywhere you want, you can make the formula hold true for any graph you choose.

Comment: Okey, but isn't there a "natural" way to think about the faces? For instance if you consider the graph $K_4$ (complete graph on 4 vertices) and let the two diagonals intersect, there's kind of a intuitive way to think about what the faces are. But maybe that intuitive idea is hard to generalize?

Comment: @mros What's the intuitive way to think about what the faces are in your example?  I'm honestly not sure what you mean.

Comment: Okey, well if you consider a square with the diagonals intersecting in the middle. The diagonals divide the "middle face" into 4 faces (the way I picture it).